# How to improve Performance with Oracle SQL Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, database-performance

The situation is I have to join more than 10 different table. In the SQL I am joining the same table 5 times. The query looks like this.

```
select * from 
Tab1
join Tab2 on Tab1.x = Tab2.x
.
.
.
join Tab10 t10 on
t10.x = 'xx' and 
t10.y = 'yy' and
t10.z = 'zz' 

join Tab10 t11 on
t11.x = 'aa' and 
t11.y = 'bb' and
t11.z = 'cc' 

join Tab10 t12 on
t12.x = 'dd' and 
t12.y = 'ee' and
t12.z = 'ff' 

join Tab10 t13 on
t13.x = 'gg' and 
t13.y = 'hh' and
t13.z = 'ii' 

join Tab10 t14 on
t14.x = 'jj' and 
t14.y = 'kk' and
t14.z = 'll'
```

The reason why this Tab10 is joined 5 times is get the different values based on the parameter. Is it possible to rewrite Tab10 join in a better way? 
I also noticed due to this Tab10 join the performance is bad.

Comment: A table like that is often a design smell. EAV tables are a very poor way to do business in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join 5 times, use `or` instead.

```
.
.
.
join Tab10 t10 on 
(t10.x = 'xx' and t10.y = 'yy' and t10.z = 'zz') or  
(t10.x = 'aa' and t10.y = 'bb' and t10.z = 'cc') or 
(t10.x = 'dd' and t10.y = 'ee' and t10.z = 'ff') or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a few joins doesn't have to mean bad performance. Create an index for the Tab10 table with the three fields that you use in the joins.

Don't use `select *`, that will reduce the performance. You will be fetching a lot of data that you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a `subselect` is more efficient than a `left outer join` one thing you should bear in mind is in the `where` clause filter by the more restrictive first. As Guffa said, adding indexes is a good point. But remember that if you add indexes in a table that is far more `writes` than reads, it might slow down `updates/insert` at that table.